# GridView rarely and randomly loses its PageIndex, what is the cause?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a custom pager control and a GridView inside an update panel on my page in my system.
It normally works fine but a few times a week there will be an error in the logs where the PageIndex of the GridView is reset to 0.

The paging works like so.

```
private void PageBackward(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    boundGridView.PageIndex = boundGridView.PageIndex - 1;
    boundGridView.DataBind();
}

private void PageForward(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    boundGridView.PageIndex = boundGridView.PageIndex + 1;
    boundGridView.DataBind();
}
```

Simple right?

When this error occurs the users are just using the system normally.
We are in a clustered environment but all the GridView data should be stored in ViewState.
I'm considering just putting the PageIndex in the Session but really I shouldn't have to.

What causes this?

Comment: does the cluster failover?

Comment: @MitchWheat I don't think so, we just have the cluster for load balancing and maintaining uptime during upgrades.

Comment: @MitchWheat We are using NLB for the cluster... I guess that does mean it fails over? I'm not really familiar with server technology...

Comment: so that means viewstate needs to be a central location...or something like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281307(v=sql.105).aspx  ... : "1.Generate a validation key and decryption key by using the autogenerate functionality provided by the .NET Framework. In the end, you must have a single <machineKey> entry that you can paste into the Web.config file for each Report Manager instance in the scale-out deployment."

Comment: Also, http://forums.asp.net/t/955145.aspx

Comment: @MitchWheat Thanks Mitch, I think I'm on the right direction now. I'll post back here when I have a solution.